# Web API consult using JSON rest API by C# ListView Application - Android returns Blank

Tags: asp.net, rest, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm facing a little problem here. The code seens to be ok, but Application is not binding the correct list that I am inserting in the WebAPI database.

What I expect to achieve:

a Listview in Cross Platform, in this case I'm testing in Android, that lists all the data in the WebAPI code as follow:

Here is the Json File that is listed on the WebAPI

```
[{"Id":1,"BusinessName":"La ventana","BusinessFantasyName":"La Ventana","BusinessArea":"Restaurante","BusinessSpecificArea":"Pizzaria","Country":"Brasil","State":"RS","City":"Rio Grande","Adress":"Av Rio Grande","Neighbourhood":"Cassino","Number":"134","Complement":"Casa","Latitude":-32.1853837,"Longitude":-52.1582284,"DateOfReg":"26/12/2017","DateOfMod":"26/12/2017","BusinessStatus":"Ativo","RegisteredBy":"Daniel Serrão"},{"Id":2,"BusinessName":"Supermercado Granabara - Cassino","BusinessFantasyName":"Supermercado Granabara - Cassino","BusinessArea":"Supermercados","BusinessSpecificArea":"Bens e Consumo","Country":"Brasil","State":"RS","City":"Rio Grande","Adress":"Av Rio Grande","Neighbourhood":"Cassino","Number":"150","Complement":"NA","Latitude":-32.1845922,"Longitude":-52.1591549,"DateOfReg":"26/12/2017","DateOfMod":"26/12/2017","BusinessStatus":"Ativo","RegisteredBy":"Daniel Serrão"}]
```

Here is the code in order to consult this WEBAPI:

```
namespace Icquire.RestClient
{ public class RestClient<T> 
{
private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:58173/api/BusinessRegs/";

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Format(WebServiceUrl));
        var BusinessReg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
        return BusinessReg;
    }

    public async Task<bool> PostAsync(T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebServiceUrl, httpContent);
        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    public async Task<bool> PutAsync(int Id, T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebServiceUrl + Id, httpContent);
        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int Id, T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(WebServiceUrl + Id);
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;           
    }



}}
```

Here is the code for the internal service:

```
namespace Icquire.Services

{ public class BusinessRegServices
{ public async Task<List<BusinessReg>> GetBusinessRegAsync()

    {
        RestClient<BusinessReg> restClient = new RestClient<BusinessReg>();
        var BusinessRegList = await restClient.GetAsync();
        return BusinessRegList;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code in order to view the Data:

```
namespace Icquire.ViewModel
{ public class BusinessRegView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<BusinessReg> _BusinessRegList
    {
        get { return _BusinessRegList; }
        set
        {
            _BusinessRegList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public List<BusinessReg> BusinessRegList { get; set; }


    public BusinessRegView()
    {
        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var businessRegServices = new BusinessRegServices();

        BusinessRegList = await businessRegServices.GetBusinessRegAsync();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
};
```

}

And here is My ListView in the contentPage:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BusinessRegList}" HasUnevenRows="True" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation ="Vertical">
                            <Label TextColor="Silver" Text="{Binding BusinessName}"/>
                            <Label TextColor="Silver" Text="{Binding Adress}"/>
                            <Label TextColor="Silver" Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The proble is that with codes above, the Binding in the ListView is returning blank. As the Json is generating corretly I think that the problem is on the Consulting to the Json file. Or inside the Services Code. does any one have a Clue?

Thanks in advance...
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your service call is actually returning data and the binding setup is correct.

Your property declaration is incorrect, it should be:

```
private List<BusinessReg> _BusinessRegList;

public List<BusinessReg> BusinessRegList
{
  get { return _BusinessRegList; }
  set
  {
     _BusinessRegList = value;
     OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

More information can be found in [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Comment: Unfortunatelly it did not work.

The App even didn't run after the changes.